# Python pandas: how to select the rows when sign changes and have miminum of the values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to find where the function crosses the line x=0. I utilized the fact that when the function crosses x-axis, its sign changes.

Now, I have a dataframe like this, I want to find the TWO rows that are closest to zeros, given that function crosses the x-axis at two points.

```
     A     value
0  105  0.662932
1  105  0.662932
2  107  0.052653 # sign changes here when A is 107
3  108 -0.228060 # among these two A 107 is closer to zero
4  110 -0.740819
5  112 -1.188906
6  142 -0.228060 # sign changes here when A is 142
7  143  0.052654 # among these two, A 143 is closer to zero
8  144  0.349638
```

Required output:

```
     A     value
2  107  0.052653 
7  143  0.052654
```

Comment: have a look at `np.sign` `np.diff` and `np.where`.  Using these you can isolate to the sign of the number, use diff to check when the sign changes, and use np.where to get the indices of where the sign actually changes.  Composing it all together shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: Can it cross the x-axis in sequential values, i.e., `-1, 1, -1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [105,  0.662932],
    [105,  0.662932],
    [107,  0.052653], # sign changes between here
    [108, -0.228060], # and here; first row has `value` closer to 0
    [110, -0.740819],
    [112, -1.188906],
    [142, -0.228060], # sign changes between here
    [143,  0.052654], # and here; second row has `value` closer to 0
    [144,  0.349638],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "value"])

# where the sign is the same between two elements, the diff is 0
# otherwise, it's either 2 or -2 (doesn't matter which for this use case)
# use periods=1 and =-1 to do a diff forwards and backwards

sign = df.value.map(np.sign)
diff1 = sign.diff(periods=1).fillna(0)
diff2 = sign.diff(periods=-1).fillna(0)

# now we have the locations where sign changes occur. We just need to extract
# the `value` values at those locations to determine which of the two possibilities
# to choose for each sign change (whichever has `value` closer to 0)

df1 = df.loc[diff1[diff1 != 0].index]
df2 = df.loc[diff2[diff2 != 0].index]
idx = np.where(abs(df1.value.values) < abs(df2.value.values), df1.index.values, df2.index.values)
df.loc[idx]
```

```
    A   value
2   107 0.052653
7   143 0.052654
```

Thanks to @Vince W. for mentioning one should use `np.where`; I was going with a more convoluted approach initially.

EDIT - see @useruser3483203's answer below which is *much* faster than this. You can improve even a bit more (2x as fast when I reran their timings) by doing the first few operations (diff, abs, compare equality) on a numpy array instead of a pandas Series too. numpy's `diff` is different than the one in pandas, though, in that it drops the first element instead of returning `NaN` for it. This means we get back the index of the first row of the sign change, instead of the second, and need to add one to get the next row.

```py
def find_min_sign_changes(df):
    vals = df.value.values
    abs_sign_diff = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(vals)))
    # idx of first row where the change is
    change_idx = np.flatnonzero(abs_sign_diff == 2)
    # +1 to get idx of second rows in the sign change too
    change_idx = np.stack((change_idx, change_idx + 1), axis=1)

    # now we have the locations where sign changes occur. We just need to extract
    # the `value` values at those locations to determine which of the two possibilities
    # to choose for each sign change (whichever has `value` closer to 0)

    min_idx = np.abs(vals[change_idx]).argmin(1)
    return df.iloc[change_idx[range(len(change_idx)), min_idx]]
```

Comment: It gives the wrong answer. Second row should be `7  143  0.052654 ` Index 7 and A is 143 NOT 142.

Comment: Just updated - I thought you wanted `A` closer to 0, but you meant `value` closer to 0

Comment: To find the first index where sign changes I found another way `idx = np.argwhere((np.diff(np.sign(df.A.values*0 - df.value.values)) != 0)`  Gives `2 and 6`

Answer (score 3):

You can generalize the approach using `numpy`:

```
a = df.value.values
u = np.sign(df.value)
m = np.flatnonzero(u.diff().abs().eq(2))

g = np.stack([m-1, m], axis=1)
v = np.abs(a[g]).argmin(1)

df.iloc[g[np.arange(g.shape[0]), v]]
```

```
     A     value
2  107  0.052653
7  143  0.052654
```

---

This solution is also going to be a lot more efficient, especially as the size scales.

```
In [122]: df = pd.concat([df]*100)

In [123]: %timeit chris(df)
870 µs ± 10 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [124]: %timeit nathan(df)
2.03 s ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [125]: %timeit df.loc[find_closest_to_zero_idx(df.value.values)]
1.81 ms ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed get a simple solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [105,  0.662932],
    [105,  0.662932],
    [107,  0.052653], # sign changes between here
    [108, -0.228060], # and here; first row has `value` closer to 0
    [110, -0.740819],
    [112, -1.188906],
    [142, -0.228060], # sign changes between here
    [143,  0.052654], # and here; second row has `value` closer to 0
    [144,  0.349638],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "value"]
```

**Solution**

```
def find_closest_to_zero_idx(arr):
    fx = np.zeros(len(arr))
    fy = np.array(arr)

    # lower index when sign changes in array
    idx = np.argwhere((np.diff(np.sign(fx - fy)) != 0) )
    nearest_to_zero = []

    # test two values before and after zero which is nearer to zero
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        if abs(arr[idx[i][0]]) < abs(arr[idx[i][0]+1]):
            nearer = idx[i][0]
            nearest_to_zero.append(nearer)
        else:
            nearer = idx[i][0]+1
            nearest_to_zero.append(nearer)


    return nearest_to_zero

idx = find_closest_to_zero_idx(df.value.values)
```

**Result**

```
idx = find_closest_to_zero_idx(df.value.values)

df.loc[idx]

     A     value
2  107  0.052653
7  143  0.052654
```

**Slow but pure pandas method**

```
df['value_shifted'] = df.value.shift(-1)
df['sign_changed'] = np.sign(df.value.values) * np.sign(df.value_shifted.values)

# lower index where sign changes
idx = df[df.sign_changed == -1.0].index.values

# make both lower and upper index from the a-axis negative so that
# we can groupby later.
for i in range(len(idx)):
    df.loc[ [idx[i], idx[i]+1], 'sign_changed'] = -1.0 * (i+1)

df1 = df[ np.sign(df.sign_changed) == -1.0]
df2 = df1.groupby('sign_changed')['value'].apply(lambda x: min(abs(x)))
df3 = df2.reset_index()

answer = df.merge(df3,on=['sign_changed','value'])
answer
     A     value  value_shifted  sign_changed
0  107  0.052653      -0.228060          -1.0
1  143  0.052654       0.349638          -2.0
```

Comment: This will only find the first two occurences

Comment: @user3483203  Fixed the bug, now it works for any number of occurrences. Thanks for finding the bug.

Comment: I added in your timings.  Your solution will always be faster than Nathan's, but the explicit iteration means it will be slower than my pure numpy solution

Comment: Also, My code has one shortcoming, there must be two values before and after x axis for all the occurrences.

Comment: that loop is going to be killer larger problem size. better to vectorize